# How to get a record in workbench by passing record name with out using rest class

Tags: rest, workbench

I knew that we can get record by passing id of a record in workbench and we can get a record by passing name of a record(using where condition) by using rest class. 
But i want to know that,

**(I might thinking, this is not possible, but to get confirmation i am posting this query)**

**can we get a record using get method in workbench with out using rest class by passing a name?**

I tried with many ways by passing many urls in workbench. But, i am getting path error always. 
Example urls which i have tried

```
/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/account?name='Mine'
/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/account?name:Mine
```

if there is any solutions, please suggest me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately thats not possible. You can fetch the records using the Id or the `externalId` field using this format.

```
curl https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Merchandise__c/MerchandiseExtID__c/123 -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

Response

```
{ 
    "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Merchandise__c",
        "url" : "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Merchandise__c/a00D0000008oWP8IAM"
     },
    "Id" : "a00D0000008oWP8IAM",
    "OwnerId" : "005D0000001KyEIIA0",
    "IsDeleted" : false,
    "Name" : "Example Merchandise",
    "CreatedDate" : "2012-07-12T17:49:01.000+0000",
    "CreatedById" : "005D0000001KyEIIA0",
    "LastModifiedDate" : "2012-07-12T17:49:01.000+0000",
    "LastModifiedById" : "005D0000001KyEIIA0",
    "SystemModstamp" : "2012-07-12T17:49:01.000+0000",
    "Description__c" : "Merch with external ID",
    "Price__c" : 10.0,
    "Total_Inventory__c" : 100.0,
    "Distributor__c" : null,
    "MerchandiseExtID__c" : 123.0
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_retrieve_with_externalid.htm)

Or as you mention in your question You need to use SOQL for other fields.

```
curl https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/query/?q=SELECT+name+from+Account -H "Authorization: Bearer token"
```

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm)

Comment: Your answer starts with "Unfortunately thats now possible" . Did you mean to say? "Unfortunately thats not possible"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so this is possible but you can always query record through REST API using Q parameter.

> > **URI /vXX.X/query/?q=SOQL query**

You can get more info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_query.htm)